# If numbers match, copy contents of Sheet1 Column P to Sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I'm using the below code. My goal is to change this row:

```vb
cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

If the number in Sheet1 A2 matches Sheet2 A2
Then copy the data from Sheet1 P2 to Sheet2 P2
(and consecutively if Sheet1 A3 = Sheet2 A3 THEN copy Sheet1 P3 to Sheet2 P3 all the way down the list).

```vb
Sub Sheet1Sheet2Compare()
    Dim lRow, x As Long
    
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    lRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    
    For Each cell In Range("A2:A" & lRow)
        x = 2
        Do
            If cell.Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, "A").Value Then
                cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End If
            x = x + 1
        Loop Until IsEmpty(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, "A"))
    Next
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Sub Sheet1Sheet2Compare()
    Dim lRow As Integer, x As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    lRow = sht1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lRow
        If sht1.Range("A" & i).Value = sht2.Range("A" & i).Value Then sht2.Range("P" & i).Value = sht1.Range("P" & i).Value
    Next i

End Sub
```